# Tkinter - destroying window after a few seconds, unless a specific event is detected

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a python script, using Tkinter and the i3ipc to display a window whenever I change focus between different windows in the i3 window manager. For those who don't know what that is, ignore that part, all I use from it is one function to get the focused window's name which I'm certain is working. I'll post the code below.

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import i3ipc
import tkinter as tk

window_width = 150
window_height = 50

i3 = i3ipc.Connection()

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

current_window = None


# This function gets the name of the focused window.
def find_focused():
    focused = i3.get_tree().find_focused()
    window_name = focused.window_class
    return window_name


def create_new(root):
    global current_window
    if current_window is not None:
        current_window.destroy()
    current_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    return current_window


def kill(root, window):
    root.quit()
    window.after(450, window.destroy())
    window.update()


"""
This is the closests I came to a solution (in my mind)

def eliminate(root, window):
    window.destroy()
    root.update()

def alternative_kill(root, window):
    window.after(450, lambda: eliminate(root, window))
    root.quit()
"""


def show_window(i3, e):

    print("ciclo")

    window_name = find_focused()

    window = create_new(root)
    window.overrideredirect(True)

    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (window_width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (window_height/2)

    window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

    canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_text(window_width/2, window_height/2, text=window_name)

    window.after(50, lambda: kill(root, window))
    # alternatively, I'd call alternative_kill instead of this
    root.mainloop()


i3.on("window::focus", show_window)

i3.main()
```

Here's my issue. With the current implementation of the code, when I switch focus, a window with the name appears and disappears after 450ms. However, if I quickly change focus many times (faster than 450ms), since each window takes 450ms to be destroyed and a new one to be created, the display of their names lags behind. So, **I'd need something to destroy the window and show a new one as soon as a focus event occurred, otherwise destroy it after 450ms.**

I've tried switching the *kill* function with *alternative_kill* (see code). I thought I could use root.quit() to quit the mainloop, making it ready to receive further events, while calling on *eliminate* to destroy the window and *root.update()* to show it. Apparently, that doesn't work and when running that code the window is only shown after the first focus change and it stops working (as in, the program keeps going but no further event is received, apparently).

EDIT: To reiterate, my objective is: destroy the window 450ms after it appears, **unless** an event happens meanwhile (focus change), in which case the window should be destroyed immediately and a new one should appear.

Comment: `window.after(450, window.destroy())` destroys the window RIGHT NOW, and 450 milliseconds later does nothing (since the return value of `.destroy()` is not a callable object).  Get rid of the `()`.

Comment: That's odd. Like I explained, the way it is like now makes it so the window DOES take 450ms to be destroyed, regardless of whether an event happens or not, while removing () from the _window.after(450, window.destroy())_ like you suggest actually makes it so the window isn't destroyed at all until a new event happens. My objective is: the window should disappear 450ms after it apperas, **unless** a new event happens meanwhile, in which case it should be immediately destroyed and replaced by a new window.

Comment: Sounds like the Tk event loop isn't running.  I don't know anything about this `i3ipc` module you're using, so I can't tell you how to integrate its event loop with Tk's, but that's something that has to be done if both are to be continuously functional.